# Caret: glmnet warning - x should be a matrix with 2 or more columns

Tags: r, r-caret, glmnet

When I pass a single numeric variable as an independent variable to glmnet in caret, I get an error message saying "x should be a matrix with 2 or more columns", however when I pass a single factor variable then the train function performs as expected. Adding a factor variable to the single numeric variable also works as expected. Why is this? It is very problematic so far. I know that with glmnet you need to use a matrix and not a data frame, however caret should take care of this transformation, as it clearly does for the factor variable. Also, I need to be able to consistently implement my analysis within the caret framework, and I need my data to be as a data frame. Here is a sample, please ignore the warnings message resulting from too few observations which is not relevant for this problem.

Any help would be much appreciated as I am going crazy!

```
df <- structure(list(Y = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
                                                                                         "Yes"), class = "factor"), A = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 
                                                                                                                          "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "N", 
                                                                                                                          "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), B = c(30, 6, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
                                                                                                                                                               4, 12, 32, 12, 12, 4, 24, 8, 12, 15, 6, 12, 12), C = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Y", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "A", "B", "C"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")



# set up the grid
  tuneGrid <- expand.grid(.alpha = seq(0, 1, 0.05), .lambda = seq(0, 2, 0.05))
  ## 10-fold CV ##
  fitControl <- trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 10, classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary) 

  #works with a single factor variable  (ignore warnings based on small sample size)
  train(Y ~ A, data=df[c("Y", "A")], method="glmnet", 
    family="binomial", trControl = fitControl, tuneGrid = tuneGrid, metric = "ROC")

  #returns and error message when a single numeric independent variable is passed
  train(Y ~ B, data=df[c("Y", "B")], method="glmnet", 
    family="binomial", trControl = fitControl, tuneGrid = tuneGrid, metric = "ROC")

  #works when a factor variable is added to the numeric variable (ignore warnings based on small sample size)
  train(Y ~ A + C, data=df[c("Y", "A", "C")], method="glmnet", 
    family="binomial", trControl = fitControl, tuneGrid = tuneGrid, metric = "ROC")
```

Comment: My guess is that `caret` is producing an appropriate design matrix, similar to the trick in Marco's answer. If you try a single factor column in `glmnet` you get the same error, because `glmnet` [is coded that way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39596763/5037901).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this trick:

```
df$ones <- rep(1, nrow(df))
train(Y ~ ones+B, data=df[c("Y", "B", "ones")], method="glmnet", 
    family="binomial", trControl = fitControl, tuneGrid = tuneGrid, metric = "ROC")
```

Answer (score 3):

The glmnet function performs a check near the top of the function:

```
np = dim(x)
if (is.null(np) | (np[2] <= 1)) 
    stop("x should be a matrix with 2 or more columns")
```

You can see the full code yourself by running `glmnet` without any parens.

I believe the reason it works with a factor, is that caret has preprocessed your data set and run `dummyVars` on any factor columns, creating a column for each level of the factor. This is common in modeling / machine-learning and sometimes referred to 1-hot encoding or binary encoding.

A column of type factor with values 'red', 'green', and 'blue' would results in three columns named 'red', 'green' and 'blue'.